# Emacs mode for the Common Logic Language

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for an Emacs mode for the ISO-standardized Common Logic (CL) language.

This language typically has the file extension `.clif`.

Comment: It seems like a s-expression syntax, so failing anything else you might see how well you get on using `lisp-mode` or `emacs-lisp-mode`? If those are no good, I imagine a workable mode could be derived from that code.